# Kendo Mask Custom Rule

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, masking, maskedtextbox, kendo-maskedtextbox

I've setup the following custom rule in a Kendo UI MaskedTextBox:

```
rules: {
    "~": /[0-9#]/
}
```

I thought this would allow `0-9` or `#` in the field, but the mask text of `~` shows up and the masked box won't let me enter anything.

Where am I going wrong with the custom mask?  How do I configure a custom mask which will allow entry into the masked text box?

Comment: What does the code for your mask look like?

Comment: It's as you see above; I thought according to the docs, this is all it should take, but it is not working...

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add a fiddle? I haven't been able to duplicate your problem.

Comment: I might be able to, but if it works for you, could you post your working setup as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to duplicate the asker's problem, but the following code should achieve the requested behavior:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#with_mask").kendoMaskedTextBox({
       mask: "~~~~~~~~~~",
       rules: {
               "~": /[0-9#]/
              }
      });
   });
</script>
```

[This Fiddle contains a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/VQmnz/44/)

---

These Kendo documentation links might be useful for any further problems:

- [Official example of basic usage](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/maskedtextbox/index)
- [User guide](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/maskedtextbox/overview)
- [Predefined mask rules](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/maskedtextbox/overview#predefined-mask-rules)